# Merging maps by adding/subtracting corresponding values

Tags: java, dictionary, addition, subtraction

I have been wondering for a few days now, what could be the least messy approach to my problem. I have a set of 10 enum types e.g. { ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE } and I use these enums as keys in a map

```
Map<MyEnumType, Integer> myMap;
```

Then I generate 100 or so of these maps, with the same keys but different values. What is the best practice for adding all of these maps into one? I mean adding up all the value of those 100 maps I have generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the enum values, and for each enum value, iterate over the maps (or vice-versa):

```
Map<MyEnumType, Integer> sumMap = new EnumMap<MyEnumType, Integer>(MyEnumType.class);
for (MyEnumType e : MyEnumType.values()) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Map<MyEnumType, Integer> map : maps) {
        sum += map.get(e); // you might want a null check here
    }
    sumMap.put(e, sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option would be to create class specific for summing integers instead of overriding previous values. Here's an examples how it's done with anonymous class:

```
public class MapSummer {

    private final Map<MyEnumType, Integer> sumMap = new HashMap<MyEnumType, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer put(MyEnumType key, Integer value) {
            return super.put(key, get(key) + value);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(Object key) {
            return super.get(key) != null ? super.get(key) : 0;
        }
    };

    public Map<MyEnumType, Integer> sum(List<Map<MyEnumType, Integer>> mapList) {
        for (Map<MyEnumType, Integer> map : mapList) {
            sumMap.putAll(map);
        }
        return sumMap;
    }

}

enum MyEnumType {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR;
}
```

And unit test:

```
public class MapSummerTest {

    private final MapSummer summer = new MapSummer();

    @Test
    public void shouldSumValuesInMap() {
        final Map<MyEnumType, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<MyEnumType, Integer>() {{
            put(ONE, 1);
            put(TWO, 2);
        }};

        final Map<MyEnumType, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<MyEnumType, Integer>() {{
            put(TWO, 2);
            put(THREE, 3);
        }};

        final Map<MyEnumType, Integer> sumMap = summer.sum(Arrays.asList(map1, map2));

        assertThat(sumMap.get(ONE), equalTo(1));
        assertThat(sumMap.get(TWO), equalTo(4));
        assertThat(sumMap.get(THREE), equalTo(3));
        assertThat(sumMap.get(FOUR), equalTo(0));
    }
}
```